# Changed Git username and need to commit/push Xcode project

Tags: xcode, github

I am not very familiar with Github.

I changed my username on the web client due to security issues.

I had an Xcode project that I was committing locally and pushing to remote.

I want to push to the same remote but can't since the username is now changed. How do I modify this in Xcode/terminal?

I also want to change the local username to the same one I have on the remote. How/where can I change this

Comment: Is the issue is that the remote location has changed, or just that something somewhere is now attempting to log you in with incorrect credentials? See https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/ if it's the former; if the latter then hopefully someone else can help as I don't know anything much about Xcode's built in pull/push — it was temporarily broken a few years ago for subrepositories and I've never quite gone back.

Comment: Not very familiar with Github terminology but all I did was change my username. I had a repo for my remote set up, but then I changed the username. Now the repo on the web client has the same files, just with a different username.

Comment: I know Github puts your username into the remote URL, I just don't know how it deals with changes. Otherwise I'd be offering an answer. Do `git remote -v` on the command line in your project directory. It'll say which path it expects `origin` (the normal name for the hosted repository) to be at. If that path no longer works, use `git remote set-url origin <new URL>`. You can get the new URL from the box at the bottom of the rightmost column of the Girhub repository page. You should then be able to push and pull just as before.

Comment: ... also this question probably belongs on different StackOverflow site (superuser maybe?) and if that resolves your question please feel free to commute it to a community wiki answer.

Comment: OK, starting to make sense. I did the remote -v. I get two lines with the same URL (old username). In parens after it says (push) and (fetch), I don't know anything about origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried checkout out one of my own GitHub projects (it's public and not that interesting but I'll use it as the example anyway).

When I go to the command line and perform `git remote -v` I am told:

```
machine:Clock-Signal user$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/TomHarte/Clock-Signal.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/TomHarte/Clock-Signal.git (push)
```

Supposing I were to change my username to HarteTom then the new remote location of my repository would become:

```
https://github.com/HarteTom/Clock-Signal.git
```

Noting that both of those locations are named as 'origin' from the first output I could perform `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/HarteTom/Clock-Signal.git`. I could confirm that with another `git remote -v` which would now say:

```
machine:Clock-Signal user$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/HarteTom/Clock-Signal.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/HarteTom/Clock-Signal.git (push)
```